# html works fine on all browsers on my computer but a href that I use as clickable links are moved on safari on iphone

Tags: iphone, html, css, safari

This is the code for the two a hrefs which I use as buttons.

```
<div style="position:absolute; left:610px; top:630px; float:left" id="stylescroll">


<font color="#33FF66"><a href="javascript:changecolor(-1)" style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none; padding-bottom:20px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></font>

</div>

<div style="position:absolute; left:760px; top:630px; float:left" id="stylescroll2">

<font color="#33FF66"><a href="javascript:changecolor(1)" style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none; padding-bottom:20px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></font>

</div>
```

Again the positioning on all the browsers on my computer work fine, however when I open the page on my iphone the a hrefs links are moved to the right on the browser.

Any ideas?

Comment: C'mon, this really needs a screenshot and full code, not an out-of-context excerpt missing all CSS.

Comment: Do you have any other CSS that may be affecting those `<a>` elements?

Comment: Guys does position absolute and float work together?

Comment: I paste this excerpt and edit it to include text instead of blanks.  All links appear to the right in FF and IE8

Comment: Are you using media queries for displaying content on your iphone? Also are you using the appropriate meta tags?

Comment: You're using deprecated `<font>` tags, `position: absolute` is not compatible with `float:`, and you're creating a link from a long string of `&nbsp;` spaces ... perhaps it's a good time to re-evaluate your design techniques.

Answer (score 0):

The screen resolution differs from a computer to a mobile device.  iPhone 4 for example, has a screen that is 960px tall, and 640px wide, whereas a computer might have 1440px by 900px.
Therefore, positioning absolute elements will show different results in different screens.

In your markup, using `left:610px` will move the element `610px` away from the left margin, thus appearing in the right side. The same goes for the other `left` and both of `top` properties.

So, your `left:610px` positions almost near the right side, only `30px` away from the right, so if you use `right:30px` instead, it will be the same on iPhone, but different on other screens.

Moreover, there is no gain of using float + position:absolute because they contradict with each other.
I don't know if this helps, but you can use `float` with `position:relative`, which will result in the ability to reposition the floated element with relation to its current position (the floated one).